# c++ using namespace std causes errors with bind () and a waiver with the iterator

Tags: c++

I have the problem when I add

```
using namespace std;
```

that the compiler says that there is no confection to long for bind.

simple example:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    long rc = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsa);
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    SOCKET acceptSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);


    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ADDR_ANY;
    rc = bind(acceptSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

    return 0;
}
```

it would be a simple one now

```
using namespace std;
```

to renounce...
but I have further:

```
    std::vector<Structs*>::iterator it = m_ClientList.begin();
    for (; it != m_ClientList.end(); ++it)
```

and when i remove the using namespace std I get the following error message:

```
C2672 "std :: invoke": no matching overloaded function found 
C2893 Function template "unknown-type std :: invoke (_Callable &&, _ Types && ...) noexcept (<expr>)" could not be specialized
```

I don't know where to put another std :: in

```
std::vector<Structs*>::iterator it = m_ClientList.begin();
```

not before iterator...

Comment: Best practice is to not include `using namespace std;`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice Put together a [mcve] that demonstrates the error you're receiving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use [`using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). You've run into the main problem it causes:

- There exists a function in the `std` namespace called `bind`.
- There exists a function in the `WinSock2` Sockets library called `bind`.

By including `using namespace std`, the compiler does not know which one to pick.

Regardless, using `using namespace std` or not, forces you to disambiguate the calls via `std::bind(...)` and `::bind(...)`

The error you are getting with `std::invoke` is a separate issue. Are you including the `<functional>` header?

---

As for this:

```cpp
std::vector<Structs*>::iterator it = m_ClientList.begin();
for (; it != m_ClientList.end(); ++it)
```

Use `auto` and a `range-based-for-loop`:

```cpp
for(auto& client : m_ClientList) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Even with `using namespace std;`, you can still disambiguate the calls by using `::bind()` to call the Winsock function in the global namespace: `rc = ::bind(acceptSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Whups. Typo. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I had already understood the problem with the ambiguity. but thanks for solving the iterator problem. For the sake of interest, I would be interested in the correct syntax for std :: vector <Structs *> :: iterator it = m_ClientList.begin (); without using the using namespace std ...